# Using seaborn FacetGrid to plot spatial grids

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, cartopy

I'm new to seaborn so excuse me if this is a dumb question... I plan on using seaborn to plot multiple facets of my spatial data (as raster data). The source data comes from netcdf files... After import and some cleanup I do have a pandas data frame of the following column layout:

```
lat lon value year
10  12  1.2   2010
10  13  1.1   2010
...
10  12  1.2   2011
...
```

I can get some visual output if I use a scatter plot (I use cartopy for plotting with geographic transforms) :

```
import seaborn as sns
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xray

ds1 = xray.open_dataset("example1.nc")['value']
ds2 = xray.open_dataset("example2.nc")['value']  
df1 = ds1.to_dataframe()
df2 = ds2.to_dataframe()  
# make lat, lon regular cols  
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)  
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)  
# add a year column
df1['year'] = 2010  
df2['year'] = 2011  
# produce the final dataframe  
df = pd.concat( [df1, df2] )  

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="year", hue="value",
                  subplot_kws=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()), size=4.5,
                  sharex=False, sharey=False, despine=False)

g.map(plt.scatter, "lon", "lat", s=5, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
```

However, I'm lost when I want to plot raster data... I guess I should use pandas.meshgrid, plot.contourf and some other magic, but I cannot for the live of me figure out how I go from pandas to faceted raster plots...

Comment: First google result: https://gist.github.com/shoyer/16db9cd187886a3effd8 from Stephan Hoyer. Might be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks. I found this page (actually that's how I got interested in the first place) and played around with the scatter plots showed there (working, no problem)... However, I'm having difficulties in translating that to raster data...
I guess I'm stuck in building a working function (like the scatterplot function in the link) that translates properly from my data frame of cols lat, lon, value, facetid to something that makes a proper image/ contour etc. ...

Comment: Can you link to a public dataset of the format you want to plot? It would be easier to make an example without having to create such a dataset.

Comment: I don't have a good link at the moment, but I extended the example a bit. Will try to find some example data...